# extracting the XML links from a web page using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to extract the XML links from a web page using Jsoup, could some one please help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example? Web page example and what link from that do you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements xmls = doc.select("a[href$=.xml]");
for (Element link : xmls) {
        System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
}
```